# Combined actions in LINQ for IEnumerable/List?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to delete every file from a directory that matches a certain condition, but I also want the items to be removed from my list (or IEnumerable) (because I want to work with that list later and don't want any items in it that are not existing anymore on the filesystem!)

An easy approach would be to gather every item that matches a certain condition into a list and then looping through the temporary list and deleting both the file and listitem from the original list. But I'd appreciate to see a solution where both of the tasks are done in one step, without creating a filtered temporary list first.

```
// non-sense code example
lstFiles.ForEach(x => x.CreationTime < __now.AddDays(maxAge * -1), x => x.Delete())
    .Remove(x);
// or...
newList/IEnumerable = lstFiles.Where(x => x.CreationTime < __now.AddDays(maxAge * -1), x.Delete()).RemoveAll(x)
```

**Alternate question:**
Can I make a list of files where every item is added that (does not) match the condition and every else gets delete? Something like an addional `.WhereNot(x => x.Delete())`?

or...

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> cleanedList =
    (from files in directory.EnumerateFiles()
     where files.CreationTime < __now.AddDays(maxAge * -1)
     wherenot files.Delete()
     select files)
```

Comment: [`ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/bwabdf9z(v=vs.80).aspx) is a method of `List<T>` and it's not related to Linq, it existed already in .NET 2.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Because of this I marked it as 'non-sense code example'. My question is related to every approach on this like e.g. `Where()` (to filter the list etc.)

Comment: Whats wrong with the standard `ForEach`?

Comment: Are you trying to remove items from a list as your'e enumerating through it? You don't want to do this; it will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make your `Delete()` method return a bool and then you can use:

```
lstFiles.RemoveAll(x => x.CreationTime < _now.AddDays(maxAge * -1) && x.Delete());
```

If the first part of the && statement fails, then the second part will not be evaluated, so deletes will only happen on the files who match the criteria.

This has the added benefit of when a delete fails it will not remove the file from your list.

Comment: This is the simplest to implement and you have a safety net if the delete fails do to access permissions, etc.

Comment: While this does answer the question, it's pretty poor practice as you're causing a very important side effect within what appears to just be a boolean expression, so this will result in much less readable code than slightly longer alternatives.

Comment: @Servy I am just showing how it could be done, not endorsing this as a best practice.  I too don't like the idea of doing two discreet things in a single statement as this leads to difficult to understand code and makes bugs that much harder to find.

Comment: That's why I wouldn't downvote something like this, I'm just warning the OP that, while it may seem slick, it's probably not a good idea to use it.  It's not a point against you for answering the question as asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do multiple operations while keeping the chaining operation, you can use Microsoft's [Interactive Extensions (IX)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ix_Experimental-Main) and the .Do and .ForEach extensions.

```
lstFiles
   .Where(x => x.CreationTime < __now.AddDays(maxAge * -1))
   .Do(x => x.DoThing1())
   .Do(x => x.DoThing2())
   .ForEach(x => x.Remove());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use different approach:
Instead of having a `List` you can have an `ObservableCollection`, attach a handler to the event `CollectionChanged` and every time an item is deleted you delete the associated file.

```
collection.CollectionChanged += ContentCollectionChanged;
[...]
public void ContentCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
    {
        foreach(var file in e.OldItems)
        {
            //Removed file
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can only need to handle the elements to remove in your collection.